# Integer solutions to a system of equations

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, integers

I was trying to find all triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy the equations
$$x^2-y-2z=4,$$ $$y^2-2z-3x=-2,$$ $$2z^2-3x-5y=-22.$$
I got through trial and error that one triple should be $(3,3,1)$. But I can neither find other integer solutions, nor prove that it's the only one.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Add the equations up, and then complete the squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution is indicated in the comments.

Still, we can just find out all complex solutions.
The first equation gives $y=x^2-2z-4$, so that we obtain two quadratic equations in $x$ and $z$. Taking the resultant of these two polynomials, we obtain
$$
(x-3)(x^6 + 6x^5 + 11x^4 - 6x^3 + 23x^2 + 192x + 348)=0.
$$
The polynomial of degree $6$ has no real root. In particular, $(x,y,z)=(3,3,1)$ is the only real solution.

Comment: How do we conclude that the degree $6$ polynomial you obtained has no solutions in real numbers?

Comment: See [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for the general case. Here it is easier.